# Packet tracer error

Tags: permissions

I just installed packet tracer on Ubuntu then when I open this message will come:

```
./PacketTracer7: ./libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./PacketTracer7)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you did not install required library for PacketTracer. To install the required package for Packet Tracer 7 on Linux, execute the following commands in Terminal.

```
1) sudo apt-get update
2) sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

If you run the ./PacketTracer7 command again and you get the same error, you should execute the next command.

```
3) cp -i /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /opt/pt/bin/
cp: overwrite '/opt/pt/bin/libcrypto.so.1.0.0'? Y -->> Press Y (Yes).
4) ./PacketTracer7
Starting Cisco Packet Tracer…
```

If you get an error trying to install the libssl1.0.0 package on Linux, update your **/etc/apt/sources.list** repository. If you are still unable to build **libssl1.0.0**, you can use the following commands.

```
1) wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
2) sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to /tmp

```
cd /tmp
```

Download libpng12-0 package

```
 wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+
deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

Wile still in /tmp run the following to install:

```
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

go to /opt/pt/bin

```
cd /opt/pt/bin
```

**THE ERROR ABOVE SEEMS LIKE YOU NEED THE REQUIRED Qt libraries**

Install all the required Qt libraries

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libqt5webkit5 libqt5multimediawidgets5
 libqt5svg5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5 libqt5sql5
```

after complete run Packet Tracer again (make sure you cd /opt/pt/bin )

```
 ./PacketTracer7
```